# javafx unable to edit tableview row data

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

i want to edit tableview row data i had some codes which edit cell data but it is not working in my project 
fxml code:

```
<TableView fx:id="table" layoutX="112.0" layoutY="25.0" prefHeight="430.0" prefWidth="505.0">
                           <columns>
                              <TableColumn fx:id="tablecol" prefWidth="490.0" text="Schedule Item">
                                  <cellValueFactory>
                      <PropertyValueFactory property="firstName" />
                  </cellValueFactory></TableColumn>
                           </columns>
                        </TableView>
```

in fxml `fx:id="tablecol"` and `fx:id="table"` are used

code:

```
@FXML
    private TableView<person1> table;
 @FXML
    private TableColumn<person1, String> tablecol;
    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

 tablecol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
tablecol.setOnEditCommit(
    new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<person1, String>>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(CellEditEvent<person1, String> t) {
            ((person1) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                ).setFirstName(t.getNewValue());
        }
    }
);         try{
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con=(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schoolmanagement","root","root");
            String sql="SELECT * FROM `scheduleitem` ";
           Statement stm=(Statement) con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=stm.executeQuery(sql);
while(rs.next()){

   table.getItems().add(new person1(rs.getString(2)));
}

        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {

        }
    }    
 }


    public class person1 {
    private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty("");

    public person1(String firstName) {
        setFirstName(firstName);

    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName.get();
    }

    public void setFirstName(String name) {
        this.firstName.set(name);
    }

    public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
        return firstName;
    }
```

please help why i am unable to edit the cell data.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `TableColumn`s are editable by default, `TableView`s are not. So you need

```
<TableView fx:id="table" editable="true" ...>
```